# php date() warning message even after setting date.timezone

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix warning from date() in PHP"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535514/how-to-fix-warning-from-date-in-php)

I have PHP set up within a chrooted environment (on an android device but this shouldnt be an issue), and have set the data.timezone in the used php.ini as required.
However I still get the warning messages.

I have checked using phpinfo() that I have changed the right php.ini but its still giving the error.

What could be causing this? my understanding is that changes you make in php.ini take effect right away am I right?

If you need any more information let me know!

Error message:

```
Warning: date(): it is not sage to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function......
```

Comment: What's the warning message?

Comment: you'll need to restart the server

Comment: Not sure about your environment or setup but in most cases you should restart the web server.

Comment: you need to restart all services to make sure changes take place !

Comment: You need to also make sure you are using a timezone listed [here](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Comment: I do not have a webserver, rather just using php to run a program that was written in php, I am not 100% familiar with php (at least this side, quite happy to code in it). And @crypticツ I am using the Europe/London time zone

Comment: @m02ph3u5 I have tried apachect1 restart and it would appear to restart everything however I still get the warning message