# I am getting warning about timezone settings on my blog page

Tags: php, wordpress, date, warnings

Am displaying [PHP Date Picker](http://www.triconsole.com/php/calendar_datepicker.php) on my blog page using shortcode. But getting below warning.

`Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Australia/Perth' for 'WST/8.0/no DST' instead in /home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/xxx/calendar/calendar_form.php on line 48`

My server PHP Version is: **5.3.19**

How do i get rid of this warning?

I tried to hide PHP warning but not success, still getting warning on it.

`error_reporting(E_ALL^ (E_WARNING | E_NOTICE));`

Also i tried to set timezone as:

`date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Perth');`

but no luck.

Now need your help guys. Thanks...

Comment: have you tried to set the default time zone in the php.ini?

Comment: Am working on my client's server, not access to change this.

Comment: This answer not working in my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535514/how-to-fix-warning-from-date-in-php. I already mention in my question i tried `error_reporting()` & `date_default_timezone_set()` but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 date_default_timezone_set("Australia/Perth");
```

or

```
date.timezone = Australia/Perth
```

use `date_default_timezone_get();` instead of `date();`

Comment: Need other alternative, Cause am using too many time `date()` function in my short-code.

Comment: try to set first the date.timezone

Comment: Error: date.timezone It say `unexpected =`

Comment: I tried both, also mentioned in my question. No luck