# Error creating connection "error null"

Tags: php, android, database, xampp

I'm creating a connection between an android mobile and a server. For this purpose I'm using XAMPP 1.8.0 with PHP: 5.4.4 on a Windows x64 7. Ten days ago, I was working with a code that worked 100%. Because of other work I couldn't work more with this project. Today I launched my app and surprise! There's a warning from function date and an error in the connection:

> **Warning**:  date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's
>   timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting
>   or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of
>   those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for
>   now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in
>   **D:\SERVER\xampp\htdocs\creater.php** on line **13**
>   [{"errorInfo":null}]

WTF have happened? In this time I updated windows with some windows update fixes and my mobile was updated from android 4.0.2 to 4.1.2.

PD. Error info comes from:

```
try{
    $link = new PDO('mysql:unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock;host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'root', '');
    $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(Exception $e) { 
    echo json_encode(array($e));
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535514/how-to-fix-warning-from-date-in-php

Comment: That resolves the date problem but I still consider that this is very strange because ten days ago I didn't have any problems with this. Anyway, the main problem is not resolved.

Comment: I'm not sure. That error comes from PHP itself, so I don't know why it would have changed. Try instead of catching Exception, try catching PDOException $e, and see if that gives you anything different.

Comment: the question is if your timezone was set 10 days ago or simply the error was not shown. However, you should definitly set the timezone. I personal prefere to use a linux vm on windows host instead of installing xampp. You dont have to deal with windows issues and it is easy to port the vm to another pc.

Comment: If I use PDOException it still says "[{"errorInfo":null}]". My code is a little bit old and last days I uploaded to use it with multipartcontent but when I leave all was ok. It is very strange.

Comment: from the docs: The MySQL Unix socket (shouldn't be used with host or port). http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

Comment: I think I get the problem. I cannot access to phpMyAdmin. It says "Not find mysql extension. Check the PHP configuration" but extension=php_mysql.dll is enabled (and aslo pdo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I resolve my problem. I think that the problem was with the socket that I don't know why, it was missing. Anyway, I thought that the fastest way to resolve it was reinstalling xampp and so I did. Just in case somebody does it, if you want to backup data, copy htpdoc folder and mysql/data. If your DDBB is InnoDB DO copy ib* files for restoring it. Without them you can't and you need to create from 0 your DDBB.