# PHP ERROR WARNING MESSAGE

Tags: php, datetime, warnings, message

How can I remove messages examples below from a website? The messages similar to the below appear on every page.

"A PHP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED
SEVERITY: WARNING
MESSAGE: DATE() [FUNCTION.DATE]: IT IS NOT SAFE TO RELY ON THE SYSTEM'S TIMEZONE SETTINGS. YOU ARE *REQUIRED* TO USE THE DATE.TIMEZONE SETTING OR THE DATE_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_SET() FUNCTION. IN CASE YOU USED ANY OF THOSE METHODS AND YOU ARE STILL GETTING THIS WARNING, YOU MOST LIKELY MISSPELLED THE TIMEZONE IDENTIFIER. WE SELECTED 'UTC' FOR 'UTC/0.0/NO DST' INSTEAD
FILENAME: COMMON/CONTENT-FOOTER.PHP
LINE NUMBER: 81"

Comment: did you try searching first (or maybe even _reading_ the error message)? Also, it's hard to fix your code without seeing it (if that's what you're asking from us)

Comment: Q: What is the PHP code in your common/content-footer.php file, line 81?

Comment: Was the error message *really* in all-caps?

Comment: message can be removed by fixing error, thats clearly described in message

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix warning from date() in PHP"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535514/how-to-fix-warning-from-date-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

Read carefully all that text. Answer is already in it.
You need to set your [date.timezone in php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) or in runtime using [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 3):

Per this link, set`date.timezone` in your php.ini file:

[How to fix warning from date() in PHP"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535514/how-to-fix-warning-from-date-in-php)

See also:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Finally, here's the PHP manual page for php.ini:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php